# Facebook android sdk 3.0 SSO

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on, facebook-android-sdk

In previous versions of the Facebook SDK we could check if a user is still signed in by using tokens. In the new 3.0 version I can't find another way other than invoking `openSession()` to check if the user is still logged in with `SSO`. But `openSession()` automatically invokes the login if the user is not saved and I don't want that. I only want to check SSO. How do I do this?

Comment: I need this too. Can't find it. WTF?

Comment: Once you create a Session, you can check the state of the Session object by calling session.getState, and if the state is in the CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED state, that means there's saved and valid tokens, and you can call open() directly without any user interaction.

Comment: Alternatively, you can call Session.openActiveSession(Context context), which according to the javadocs, will only open the session if it does not require user interaction.

Comment: In what scenario would you use openActiveSessionFromCache

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made a helper function that to check if the user is still logged in (or actually has an active session) for me in my app:

```
public static boolean isActive() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return session.isOpened();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I keep getting  "{Session state:CLOSED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:234242323423434}" in the session

Comment: I can see some people have problems with this. First of all make sure that your keys are correct in the FB app. I recall having some issue with this. My current flow that works for me is 1. check isActive(); no? 2. call openSession() 3. if error & session!=null ->session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();

Comment: In what scenario would you use openActiveSessionFromCache

Comment: I am using 3.23.0 version. Session.getActiveSession() always returning null when I am checking in splash screen though user is logged in previously.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can call Session.openActiveSession(Context context), which according to the javadocs, will only open the session if it does not require user interaction. – Ming Li