# Facebook login via app VS via device browser in android app

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

This problem's been bugging me a lot. On my emulator, ofcourse, there's no facebook app there so when I trigger the open active session it goes to my browser. Now, I tested it on a device with facebook app and it triggers the app and ask for a login. Here's where the problem comes in, on the emulator or a device without an facebook app, it recognizes the session correctly, using this code.

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    //check if user is logged in at facebook

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        Log.i("", "Session Open");
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {
                  facebookId = user.getId();
                  loginType = 2;
                  LogMeIn();

              }
            }
          });
    } 
    else 
    {
        Log.i("", "Session Closed");
        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Log.i("", "Session Open");
              // make request to the /me API
              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  Log.i("", "Complete");
                  if (user != null) {
                      facebookId = user.getId();
                      loginType = 2;
                      LogMeIn();

                  }
                }
              });
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("", "Session Closed");
            }
          }
        });
    }
```

But when in a device that has a faceboook app, the session is always null. So the tendency is to fire up again the Session.openActiveSession and I always end up getting a session closed whenever I check it. Any ideas guys on what's the problem? Is my approach wrong that's why it only works well on facebook login via browser? Any help will be full appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable session tracking in the Facebook SDK? You need to create a `UiLifecycleHelper` in your `Activity`'s `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

The `callback` which is passed into the constructor is the same one you created in your above code (you did it anonymously).

After this you need to make matching calls in your `Activity`'s lifecycle methods to the same ones of the `UiLifecycleHelper`. This will allow the Facebook SDK to track your session.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

You can find more details here in their [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook#step2). You probably followed their simpler "Getting Started" tutorial instead of the more indepth "Login" one. Whether or not the user is logging in through the app (because it's installed) or the browser shouldn't affect the session tracking if you have it set up properly.