# Facebook login and android, what approach to use

Tags: android, android-fragments, authentication, facebook-android-sdk, android-fragmentactivity

I am a bit confused with facebook login procedure.

At the moment my application works like this:

1. Login activity where user logs in and starts fragment activity
2. Fragment activity with viewpager and 3 fragments

This works, but there is a problem, everytime user starts an app Login activity is called. How can i bypass this if session is active or even better how can i implement this in my Fragment activity.

For example if there is no user logged in, login window/fragment shows and then is redirected back to viewpager and default 3 fragments.

I was following this tutorial

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook

Problem with this tutorial is that it opens Main Fragment and thats it, there is no "redirecting" and i am not sure how to come back to my viewpager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are familiar with android and java properly use an asynctask to get the logged in facebook user using a session than you can make a decider thread in case the session.isOpen() boolean value is true go to some activity and in case it's false go to your login activity - [this thread also have a similar question to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402775/android-facebook-sdk-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in-or-not) 

plus you can find some more info on sessions over [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/)

Comment: Thank you for your time and input.

Session is not my main problem i understand that, i dont know how or better where to put login button.

To be completely honest i want to avoid Login activity, because it is a launcher activity and is started everytime, even if im logged i still see that activity for a moment. According to facebook tutorial, they are using fragment for logging in, thats why i'd like to use that approach, so everytime fragment activity is launched.

So if i start login fragment i override my viewpager and i dont know how to come back.

i hope that make sense.

Comment: Im sorry, I didnt quite got you - can you try and make that clearer?
essentially you can avoid that whole mess by using sharedprefernces - once the user login using his facebook account set a boolean flag in the sharedprefernces to true and look for that flag when you launcher activity starts if it is set to true go to your first activity in case it's not you can go to the login activity

Comment: I posted an "answer" where i described what i wanna do. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if was unclear about my question, i found a solution googling around, i cant believe i didnt see this before:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate/

This answered all of my questions.

Comment: Hi @gregaj that is what I meant when I told you to use a session if it helped you, you can accept my answer =)